# Structure Array not printing correctly | C++

Tags: arrays, char, structure

This is the structure

```
struct Student{
    char firstName[MAX_LEN + 1];
    char lastName[MAX_LEN + 1];
    float gpa;
};
```

So let me say that StudentList1 has the correct data.

count Struct1 is how many names are entered.

```
Student StudentList1[10];

int count5 = 0, countfName = 0, countlName = 0;

while(count5 < countStruct1)
{
    while(StudentList1[count5].firstName[countfName] != '\0')
    {
        StudentList2[count5].firstName[countfName] = 
            StudentList1[count5].firstName[countfName];
        countfName++;
    }

    while(StudentList1[count5].lastName[countlName] != '\0')
    {
        StudentList2[count5].lastName[countlName] =
            StudentList1[count5].lastName[countlName];
        countlName++;
    }
        StudentList2[count5].gpa = StudentList1[count5].gpa;
        count5++;
}
```

Now for some reason when I try this code, not using the arrays for characters of the last name and first name

```
while(count6 < count5)
    {
        cout << "Name: " << StudentList2[count6].firstName << " " << StudentList2[count6].lastName << "\n";
        count6++;
    }
```

Now when I try this doing it like this I just get a bunch of garbage, I get the first name printed but after that a whole bunch of garbage and the last name too but just garbage in between.

Comment: It sounds like your strings are not null terminated.  For instance `[B][o][b][0]`

Comment: Is there another sentinel I can choose other than null?

Comment: The firstname and lastname in StudentList2 need `\0` at the end. Do that after coming out of each while loop.

Comment: @user3387140 - Yes, you can use another 'sentinel' than null.   You can also replace 'a' with 'z' but it would be crazy to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're forgetting the terminating zero when you copy.

Since structs are copyable, you can do it like this:

```
while (count5 < countStruct1)
{
    StudentList2[count5] = StudentList1[count5];
    count5++;
}
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < countStruct1; i++)
{
    StudentList2[i] = StudentList1[i];
}
```

which are slightly less error-prone.

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot that, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
while(StudentList1[count5].firstName[countfName] != '\0')
{
    StudentList2[count5].firstName[countfName] = 
        StudentList1[count5].firstName[countfName];
    countfName++;
}
```

You have it stop when it hits the '\0', but you never re-write that '\0' to the end of the `StudentList2`

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to copy the terminating zero:

```
StudentList2[count5].firstName[countfName] = '\0';
StudentList2[count5].lastName[countlName] = '\0';
```

then you need to reset your counters:

```
countfName = countlName = 0;
```

you should do this before the `count5++` in your outermost `while` loop